# Is there any way to make a PC or laptop boot into an OS on a external hard drive ONLY if you spam/hold a key on startup

Tags: boot

I was wondering if there was a way to make a PC or laptop boot into a OS on a external hard drive ONLY if you hold/spam a specific key (at the same time when you would open the bios settings)

For example: I turn on my laptop/PC with an external hard drive connected and hold nothing and it boots into windows. Then I restart the laptop/PC with the external hard drive connected, hold/spam F1 (or another key) on boot and it boots into Linux or another OS.

If not in any conventional manner, could you (in theory) edit some code to add this feature? (This obviously would have some risks involved)

Answer (score 0):

Different BIOSes work differently.  Most allow you to change the boot order, and some allow you to disable specific devices from the boot order list.  Most allow you to push a button before BIOS to see the list of boot devices.  I've never seen a Windows PC that let you spam a key at BIOS time for a specific boot device without going to the list.

Macs used to let you hold down C to start from the optical disk.  You can still hold down Option to see the boot device list.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of the boot order at first but thought it would be nice to be able to leave my external hard drive plugged in when I restart and not have linux pop up when it's not wanted.

Comment: @W0LFB0MB UEFI or old BIOS? Methods are different.

Comment: I dont know, though most modern day computers use UEFI so I guess that.

Comment: Again, most of them let you choose boot order, so you should be able to move the external drive lower in the priority.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky to get it to work for a drive across different computers, so let's assume that you're only connecting the external drive to one machine (or that you want this convenience on the one particular combination)

You could set up the system to try to boot from the *external* drive by default/before the internal drive.

Then configure the *external* drive to boot off from the *internal* drive by default.

That way, if the external drive is not connected, the system will boot the OS on the internal drive. When the external drive is connected, it will still boot the OS on the internal drive by default, unless you press a key to stop the boot process, in which case you can select the OS of the external drive.

This  has many caveats. First, I assume you're using BIOS and not UEFI. Moreover, you still need to do one more step to boot from the external drive other than pressing one key. However, this could be a starting point for your solution

Good luck!